# setlocale doesn't work with my language, how to create logic about that?

Tags: php, date

setlocale doesn't work and i tried to create some logic to do what i want:

I have that string `string(19) "2017-08-29 11:27:24"` I want to get month (08 in that case) to get from array bellow on position 08 a.k.a "Август". And convert it to date again.

```
$amonths=array('01'=>'Януари','02'=>'Февруари','03'=>'Март','04'=>'Април','05'=>'Май','06'=>'Юни','07'=>'Юли','08'=>'Август','09'=>'Септември','10'=>'Октомври','11'=>'Ноември','12'=>'Декември');
```

And then to use `date('j F Y', some variable)`. The result will be `"29 Август 2017"` not `"29 August 2017"`

Comment: I'd say change your lookup array to translate from English, not 2-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace strings with confidence if you replace the the full month name from English rather than numbers.  Something like this will work:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/428e2713ee6b590d3db9199dc2e7bcea50f56fdb))

```
$lookup=['January'=>'Януари',
        'February'=>'Февруари',
        'March'=>'Март',
        'April'=>'Април',
        'May'=>'Май',
        'June'=>'Юни',
        'July'=>'Юли',
        'August'=>'Август',
        'September'=>'Септември',
        'October'=>'Октомври',
        'November'=>'Ноември',
        'December'=>'Декември'];
$date=date('j F Y',strtotime("2017-08-29 11:27:24"));
echo str_replace(array_keys($lookup),$lookup,$date);
```

Output:

```
29 Август 2017
```